# Export the information of Sankey Diagrams from an HTML file

Tags: python, html

A Three Field Sankey Diagram is stored as HTML. The original diagram is so complicated and I want to export its information into a CSV file. I would appreciate it if you provide a Python script to do this.
A simple example of such an HTML file is attached here: https://filebin.net/il5oh5un8hdtddy0/Sankey-Diagram.html
Here is what  theHTML file represents: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRGFq.png

Here is the table that I wish to extract from it:

| DE | CR | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bibliographic coupling | small h, 1973 ... | science |
|  | kessler mm, 1956 ... | networks |
|  |  | indicators |

In this file, for the first item in middle (bibliographic coupling) I want to export the references on the left side (small h, 1973 ..., kessler mm, 1956 ...  ). Also, I want to export the list of items on the right side connected to this item (science, networks, indicators).

Comment: Some of the links don't work. please also provide code that you have tried

Comment: Thanks for your reply @marcadian. The broken mirror for the HTML file is removed. I could not find any clues to relate the HTML data to a code.